# How to return node from py2neo graph query?

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j, py2neo

How can i use the result and convert it to node or relationship from `graph.run` for eg.

```
result = graph.run('match (x:Person) return x')
```

How can i convert result to Py2neo v3 node/relationship?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to obtain the node from your query is to use `evaluate` instead of `run`:

```
my_node = graph.evaluate('match (x:Person) return x')
```

This method returns the first value from the first record returned. In this case, your node.

http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Graph.evaluate

Comment: Can we retrieve just the relationship as well using `graph.evaluate()`??

Comment: Something like: `my_rel= graph.evaluate('match (:Person {name:"Foo"})-[rel]->(:Person {name:"Bar"}) return r')`

Comment: i tried this however if i try to delete a relationship returned thus i get error

Comment: `rel = graph.evaluate("match (x:XaudioUser)-[m:MAINTAINS]->(p) return m")
print rel
graph.delete(rel)` on running this i get `ConstraintError: Cannot delete node<3>, because it still has relationships. To delete this node, you must first delete its relationships.` since the relation consists of the nodes as well, however i only want to retrieve the relationship

Comment: found the solution : using `graph.separate(rel)` after obtaining relationship worked. thank you , I am just a beginner with py2neo

Answer (score 0):

For `Py2neo 1.6.7` you can use `GraphDatabaseService`'s method [`find`](http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/graphs_nodes_relationships/#py2neo.neo4j.GraphDatabaseService.find) that iterates through a set of labelled nodes, optionally filtering by property key and value, e.g.:

```
from py2neo import neo4j
# pass the base URI of your neo4j database as arg
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService('http://localhost:7474/db/data/') 
resultset = graph_db.find('Person')
```

For `Py2neo 3.0` you can use `Graph`'s method [`find`](http://py2neo.org/v3/database.html#py2neo.database.Graph.find) that yields all **nodes** with a given label, optionally filtering by property key and value. So, for your example:

```
from py2neo import Graph
graph_db = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
resultset = graph_db.find('Person')
```

Finally, an important *caveat* from official doc:

> Note also that Py2neo is developed and tested exclusively under Linux
>   using standard CPython distributions. While other operating systems and Python distributions may work, support for these is not available.

Comment: acc. to new api neo4j does not exist `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name neo4j
`

Comment: I m looking for a way to parse/ convert it into node/relationship accordingly

Comment: The resultset is an iterator yelding nodes/rels.

Comment: I am using py2neo version 3.1.1 . When i try to import neo4j it gives the following `>>> from py2neo import neo4j
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name neo4j`

Comment: neo4j does not exist in v3 what you are telling might be used with py2neo v2

Comment: I installed it using pip

Comment: please check for version 3 . neo4j does not exist in py2neo v3 onwards

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7.x?

Comment: yes python2.7.12 you can refer from here its available for 2.7.x https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2neo/2.0

Comment: So your stack is: Python 2.7.12 and [Py2neo 3](http://py2neo.org/v3/#installation) isn't it?

Comment: I edited my answer to consider Pyt2neo 3. Hope this helps.

Comment: @superciccio14 I got the same error:
`>>> import py2neo
from py2neo import Graph
ImportError: cannot import name Graph`.
 I am using Python 3.3.5, py2neo 3.1.2 and pip 6.0.6. Please how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to generate a list based on the generator returned by cypher.execute.

```
result = graph.cypher.execute('match (x:Person) return x')
nodes = [n for n in result]
```

Do note that nodes queried like this are records. TO access the real nodes select the attribute r of each object. :

```
l_nodes = map(lambda node : node.r, nodes)
```